# NonLinearModelFit Usage Help

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I am using FindFit to fit a piecewise linear interpolant (vs. x) to data (vs. t) using a convolution. The FindFit portion of my notebook is attached below. The fit appears to be reasonable despite warnings on lack of convergence, but I'd like to use the diagnostics provided by NonLinearModelFit to dig a bit more deeply into the solution, and to guide additional work where the fit will be regularized with a smoothness penalty. Unfortunately, I have not figured out how to do so. I suspect that this is a (lack of) user skill on my part, and would appreciate any guidance on how to obtain the equivalent to a table of solution values using NonLinearModelFit instead of FindFit. Here Table[lnw[i], {i, n}] is the list of parameters determined by FindFit.

FindFit implementation:

```
n = Length[xNodes]
weight[i_, t_] := wNodes[[i]]*(F[xNodes[[i + 1]], t] - F[xNodes[[i]], t])
weight[n, t_] := wNodes[[n]]*(F[Infinity, t] - F[xNodes[[n]], t])
model = {Sum[Exp[lnw[i]]*weight[i, t], {i, n}]};
fit = FindFit[{tData, VdAvgData}\[Transpose], model, Table[{lnw[i], 0}, {i, n}], t];
wNodesFit = Table[Exp[lnw[i]]*wNodes[[i]], {i, n}] /. fit;
```

Comment: Could you include the data as well so we can run the code?

Comment: If you've got it working for `FindFit`, then use the parameter estimates for starting values in `NonlinearModelFit`.  And if you don't have convergence, you should not trust the answers and try `MaxIterations -> 5000`.

Comment: `NonLinearModelFit[...,Method->"NMinimize"]` works without parameter estimates!

Comment: Thank you all for the rapid replies. In reverse order: (3) Thank you. Sounds useful, but not my actual issue in this case. (2) JimB: If you could expand on your answer that would be great. I have found the documentation for NonLinearModelFit a bit opaque, so a simple transcription of my FindFit solution would be very helpful. (1) I'll see if I can get a simpler example. This algorithm is running as part of a much larger notebook, so that'll take some time/work.